# Apply formula to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which I know works, I am applying a SUMIF formula to a range of cells.  It works but it add a load of extra row at the bottom that shouldn't be there.  I tried adding in a do until loop but it gets stuck in an infinite loop and crashes.

This is my first lot of code which works but adds the extra row in only on the columns which have been copied over.

```
    Dim z As Workbook   'Budget Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook   'Formatted - current workbook
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim budgLastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set y = Workbooks("DLT.xlsm")
    Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Reports\Budget.xlsx")

'Apply function to columns to pull costing data
    With y.Worksheets("DLT")
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

            For Each rng In .Range("AI22:AI" & lastRow)
                rng.Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E" & rng.Row & ",'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!H:H)"
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            Next rng

            For Each rng In .Range("AJ22:AJ" & lastRow)
                rng.Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E" & rng.Row & ",'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!I:I)"
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            Next rng

            For Each rng In .Range("AN22:AN" & lastRow)
                rng.Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E" & rng.Row & ",'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!E:E)"
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            Next rng

            For Each rng In .Range("AO22:AO" & lastRow)
                rng.Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E" & rng.Row & ",'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!G:G)"
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            Next rng

    End With
```

I think the other additional rows have been copied because the budget workbook contains more data then the formatted work book.  I have know thought to possibly delete the other unnecessary row which have been copied cross.

So I have added this small piece of code in

```
    With y.Worksheets("Formatted")
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        budgLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 35).End(xlUp).Row
        Rows("AI" & lastRow & ":AO" & budgLastRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

I get an application-defined error Object defined error on the line

```
 Rows("AI" & lastRow & ":AO" & budgLastRow).EntireRow.Delete
```

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but its the only way I could think of.  I am fairly new to VBA only been coding a couple of months so mostly just try out different ways and see what works.  Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't properly qualify the ranges for the `lastRow` variable:

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
```

Note the dots before `Cells` and `Rows`.

A couple of additional points:

Always use `Long` rather than `Integer` for row variables as there are more rows in a sheet than an Integer can hold.

You don't need to loop to put the same formula in a column of cells.

```
Dim z                     As Workbook   'Budget Workbook
Dim y                     As Workbook   'Formatted - current workbook
Dim lastRow               As Long
Dim budgLastRow           As Long

Set y = Workbooks("DLT.xlsm")
Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Reports\Budget.xlsx")

'Apply function to columns to pull costing data
With y.Worksheets("DLT")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("AI22:AJ" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E22,'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!H:H)"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

    With .Range("AN22:AN" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E22,'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!E:E)"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

    With .Range("AO22:AO" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=SUMIF('[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!$C:$C,$E22,'[Budget.xlsx]DynamicReport'!G:G)"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

End With
```